# Verifying the consistency of a quantum field theoretic cross-section formula

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, large-hadron-collider, elementary-particles

Consider the scattering $$e^-e^-\rightarrow e^-e^-$$ in QED. The cross-section is a Lorentz invariant quantity and therefore, given by $$\sigma=\sigma(m_e,e,s,\theta)$$ where electron mass $m_e$, electron charge $e$ etc are running mass and running charge. They change with the centre-of-mass energy. $\theta$ is the scattering angle and $s$ stands for the Mandelstam variable.

QED gives a finite formula for the RHS. LHS is measured directly from experiments by measuring the scattered flux of particles in a given direction $(\theta,\phi)$. In order to check the consistency i.e., whether LHS=RHS, we have to put values of $m_e$, $e$ on the RHS by independently measuring $m_e$ and $e$ (at the colliding energy).

$m_e$ can be measured by measuring four-momenta of the scattered electrons and using dispersion relation, and by similarly measuring $e$. Is that correct?

However, if a scattering was mediated by Z/W boson as the virtual particle, the expression for $\sigma$ would contain the mass of W boson at that energy. But I believe, Z/W boson mass cannot be recovered here by measuring the four-momenta of the scattered particles. This is because, being a virtual particle, it doesn't obey energy-momentum relation.

How does one verify then the consistency of the corresponding scattering cross-section formula?

Comment: What does *"if a scattering was mediated by Z/W boson as the virtual particle"* mean? You cannot determine "which" of the diagrams describing a scattering "actually happened" because the diagrams do not really depict actual processes to begin with. It would be like asking "which path did the electron take?" *after* detecting it at the screen in a double-slit experiment.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I meant, consider a process mediated by W boson as the internal line. May be many higher order diagrams also contribute. In any case, after you renormalize, you're left with a finite scattering cross-section formula that carries physical W boson at the colliding energy as an input on the RHS. My question is, if W is virtual, how do you measure its mass? that is also running. Right?

Comment: @ACuriousMind- In other words consider a QFT in which a scattering occurs via exchange of a massive internal boson i.e., virtual. I renormalize, express the result in terms of physical masses. Now I need physical masses as the experimental input to match with the QFT formula. If it match, I verify the consistency of my prediction.

Comment: @ACuriousMind $G^0$, Q-weak and possibly other experiments have *measured* the weak electron-proton scattering cross-section by isolating the parity violating component in polarized beam experiments. I'm not aware, off the top of my head, if the week electron-electron or electron-positron scattering cross-sections have been measured. To be sure this only insures that a parity violating weak process was part of the event, not that the leading $Z$-exchange diagram "actually happened", but it probes that physics none-the-less.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand your question, but I can perhaps provide a partial answer.

As ACuriousMind pointed out, the cross-section would be a superposition of all possible exchanges that can take place. So what you'll see in a single event would be the combined effect of the exchanges that are allowed in the process.

However, it is possible to see the effect of the $Z_0$-exchange. It should show up as a resonance. If the exchange energy is close to the mass of the $Z_0$ then the cross-section increases. So, after you have accumulated some data and then plot the cross-section as a function of the energy then the curve would show a bump at the energy that conrresponds to the mass of the $Z_0$.

Comment: You can also isolate the weak interaction at low $Q^2$ (or $t$ if you like the Mandelstam variables) because the whole parity violating part of the cross-section involved a weak contribution (at tree order or in a correction diagram, but it has to be there).